# Changing Resolution with Inverse STFT

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, signal-processing, image-processing

I want to take the 2-dimensional discrete STFT of an image with a Gaussian window (or periodized Gaussian). When I recover the image with the inverse transform and dual window, I want to increase the sampling rate to recover an image with increased resolution so that I'll be sampling the trigonometric functions at more points.

I implemented the transform and inverse without changing the sampling using the LTFAT package in Matlab, but I can't figure out how to do the upsampling. I ran into the problem of not being able to sample the dual window properly.  Maybe the equation for the dual window doesn't work for this.  Any suggestions concerning the theory or the implementation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you zeropad the frequency samples before you transform them back to the spatial domain?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how that would solve the problem.  Would I just use the dual window for the longer Gaussian window?  That's different than an upsampled version of the original dual window.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "recover an image with increased resolution"? Do you just want to upsample your image? You can't increase the resolution since that will be determined by the spatial-domain support of the original image.

Comment: I want to perform superresolution.  It's not necessarily upsampling in the usual sense because one could increase the image size by a factor so that the original points aren't part of the new image.  For simplicity's sake, I want to sample at twice the rate in each direction so that, for example, a 256x256 image turns into a 512x512 image.  Using the STFT assumes that the weighted trigonometric functions used in the transform to represent the image provide a good approximation at other points as well.